# PySpark: OutOfMemoryError at AbstractStringBuilder.hugeCapacity

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, out-of-memory

I keep getting the error below. Regarding the stacktrace it looks like I'm somehow generating a huge string?! However I cannot retrace the location in the script, where this could happen.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hadoop/script.py", line 294, in <module>
    oRunner.runReports()
  File "/home/hadoop/script.py", line 176, in runReports
    self.getWriterByTableName(df, "table", True)
  File "/home/hadoop/script.py", line 56, in getWriterByTableName
    df.write.parquet('s3n://folder/'+filname+'.parquet')
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 804, in parquet
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o10162.parquet.
: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.hugeCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:161)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.newCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:155)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:125)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:448)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
    at scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:561)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.generateTreeString(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$generateTreeString$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:574)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$generateTreeString$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:574)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:574)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:568)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:568)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.generateTreeString(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:396)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.generateTreeString(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.generateTreeString(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:396)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.generateTreeString(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$generateTreeString$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:574)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$generateTreeString$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:574)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:574)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.generateTreeString(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:396)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.generateTreeString(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$generateTreeString$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:574)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$generateTreeString$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:574)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:574)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:568)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:568)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.generateTreeString(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:396)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.generateTreeString(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:568)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$generateTreeString$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:574)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$generateTreeString$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:574)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:574)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$generateTreeString$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:574)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$generateTreeString$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:574)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:574)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$generateTreeString$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:574)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$generateTreeString$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:574)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:574)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:576)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.treeString(TreeNode.scala:480)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$toString$2.apply(QueryExecution.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$toString$2.apply(QueryExecution.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.stringOrError(QueryExecution.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toString(QueryExecution.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:547)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My spark conf looks like follows:

```
--conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=20G 
--num-executors 40 --driver-memory 90G 
--executor-memory 40G 
--executor-cores 5
```

Looks like changing or increasing those values doesn't have any effect.

The dataframe itself is not big at all. It has less than 100 rows. The logical plan of the dataframe is quite complex.

Any hints are appreciated :).

Thanks!

Edit:

The function that seems to cause the issue. It remaps some values in a DF to another value.

```
def mapDf(self, df, mode = "tp"):

    if self.sMap is not None:
        oMap = json.loads(self.sMap)['mapping']
        oMap = json.loads(oMap)
        aMap = []

        i = 0
        for sNewName, aChannels in oMap.items():
            for sOldName in aChannels:
                aMap.append({})
                aMap[i]['new_name'] = sNewName
                aMap[i]['old_name'] = sOldName
                i = i + 1
        aMap = json.dumps(aMap)
        dfJson = self.spark.read.json(self.spark.sparkContext.parallelize([aMap]))
        dfTPTemp = df.join(dfJson, [f.lower(dfJson['old_name']) == f.lower(df['name'])], 'left')
        dfTPNoMap = dfTPTemp.filter('new_name is null').drop('new_name').drop('old_name')
        dfTPMap = dfTPTemp.filter('new_name is not null').drop('name').drop('old_name').withColumnRenamed(
        'new_name', 'name')


        df = dfTPMap.unionAll(dfTPNoMap)
    return df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue while I could't figure the actual problem.

Before calling `.parqet('file.csv')` I found out, that there was a function which increased the complexity of dataframe a lot. Means that commenting out this function let the code run without issues.

My workaround is to write this dataframe to a parquet file before calling this function, reload the just saved parquet, call the mentioned function afterwards.

After this calling `.parqet('file.csv')` will work.

Somehow it seems to simplifiy complex dataframes, if you save it temporary to a file and reload it.

Comment: You have two questions - one on parquet, one on this function. Do you know the function you commented out? I can tell you that writing a dataframe to parquet removes the lineage of a dataframe; this makes Spark's engine start with the data in the parquet file instead of going back to the start of the lineage to calculate everything all over again. Spark is a lazy engine so it doesn't persist outputs unless it needs to - or you tell it to.

Can you edit with the function name and I'll take a look?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer! I've edited the post and added the function. Basically just a join and and a union. Nothing special...